# errors with running java utility

Tags: java

i try to run a redy-made java script base2genetic.jar
(taken from http://faculty.washington.edu/browning/beagle_utilities/utilities.html#base2genetic)
and i receive the following message:

> [user@aurhap_map_genetic_maps]$ cat clust_1.txt | java -Xmx2g -jar base2genetic.jar 2 mapfile.txt > gen1_clust_1.txt

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "position"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
        at beagleutil.Base2Genetic.a(Unknown Source)
        at beagleutil.Base2Genetic.main(Unknown Source)
```

Could you suggest what is wrong? 
thank u a lot!!

Comment: Can you post the exact command entered? It sounds like you have a problem with your command line arguments

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you've supplied the string "position" in an input file or as a command argument, and the program is expecting a floating point number instead.

In fact, looking at the page you linked to, I'd say that it is your input file that is the problem.

Comment: thank u! will look to my input (may be its becase number is 0.000.. and needs to be 0,000..)

Answer (score 0):

looks like some input string *position* cannot be formatted as a number.